# meteor users not synchronize published sub fields of profile

Tags: javascript, meteor, user-accounts

Working on my social app I've found a strange behavior in the collection Meteor.users, this problem does not occur with other Collections using the same methodologies

I would like to have an initial list of users downloading a minimum number of information for everyone and when I open the panel to a specific user I subscribe a different showing more information if the specified user is a friend of mine.

But after subscribe the client collection Meteor.users is not updated!

**CLIENT**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    Meteor.subscribe('usersByIds', Meteor.user().profile.friends, function() {

        //... make users list panel using minimal fields

    });

    //performed when click on a user
    function userLoadInfo(userId) {

        Meteor.subscribe('userById', userId, function() {

            var userProfile = Meteor.users.findOne(userId).profile;

            //...
            //make template user panel using full or minimal user fields
            //...

            //BUT NOT WORK!

            //HERE Meteor.users.findOne(userId) keep minial user fields!!
            //then if userId is my friend!

        });         
    }
});
```

**SERVER**

```
//return minimal user fields
getUsersByIds = function(usersIds) {

    return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: usersIds} },
                            {
                                fields: {
                                    'profile.username':1,
                                    'profile.avatar_url':1
                                }
                            });
};

//return all user fields
getFriendById = function(userId) {

    return Meteor.users.find({_id: userId},
                            {
                                fields: {
                                    'profile.username':1,
                                    'profile.avatar_url':1
                                    //ADDITIONAL FIELDS                         
                                    'profile.online':1,
                                    'profile.favorites':1,
                                    'profile.friends':1
                                }
                            });
};

//Publish all users, with minimal fields
Meteor.publish('usersByIds', function(userId) {

    if(!this.userId) return null;

    return getUsersByIds( [userId] );
});

//Publish user, IF IS FRIEND full fields
Meteor.publish('userById', function(userId) {

    if(!this.userId) return null;

    var userCur = getFriendById(userId),
        userProfile = userCur.fetch()[0].profile;

    if(userProfile.friends.indexOf(this.userId) != -1)  //I'm in his friends list
    {
        console.log('userdById IS FRIEND');
        return userCur;     //all fields
    }
    else
        return getUsersByIds( [userId] );   //minimal fields
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that your full user subscription is being called on button click? Have you checked in your console to verify that the data is absent? You may want to use .ready() for your subscription instead of attempting to use a callback.

Comment: Yes im sure beacuse server print the log: 'userdById IS FRIEND' but the client collection is not updated!
I tried with this.ready() inside publish but not work! :(
I'm used chrome console to test users colllection Meteor.users.find().fetch().. in client but data is not updated with full fields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation or bug in DDP.  See [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/903).

A workaround is to move data out of `users.profile`.

Like this:

```
//limited publish
Meteor.publish( 'basicData', function( reqId ){
  if ( this.userId ) {      

    return Meteor.users.find({_id: reqId },{
      fields: { 'profile.username':1,'profile.avatar_url':1}
    });
  } 
  else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

//friend Publish
Meteor.publish( 'friendData', function( reqId ){
  if ( this.userId ) {

    return Meteor.users.find( {_id: reqId, 'friendProfile.friends': this.userId }, {
      fields: {
        'friendProfile.online':1, 
        'friendProfile.favorites':1,
        'friendProfile.friends':1
      }
    });
  } 
  else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

//example user
var someUser = {
   _id: "abcd",
   profile: {
     username: "abcd",
     avatar_url: "http://pic.jpg"
   },
   friendProfile: {
     friends: ['bcde', 'cdef' ],
     online: true,
     favorites: ['stuff', 'otherStuff' ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this way(double publish) but if I request before limited publish and after full publish... in Meteor.users (client) the fields remain limited!  the subscription work(i see logs) but in local collection data no change!
I want to clarify that this problem only appears for Meteor.users collection, for other collection it work!

Comment: using .rewind() does not change the behavior :(

Comment: Did some more looking.  This is a known bug which for some reasone is remaining undocumented - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/903.  It is not just the user documents but any publish of subdocuments.  So the workaround is to move some of your data out of the profile field.

Comment: @user728291 I don't think it is a bug per se. Rather just to make the protocol less complex.

Comment: ok but.. beacause this thing is not documented I would say that this is a bug

Comment: @user728291 i see your edit, but i know the problem persists in subfields inside friendProfile.. or not? for example if on db update 'friendProfile.online' to 0 the client not sinchronize

Comment: The problem as I understand it is that only one publish function can control the subfields for the fields it publishes for a given document.  I think this relates to the distinction between 'added' and 'changed' inside publish where a client is getting confusing information if it is told to add the same doc twice rather than to update a doc it already has.

Comment: If you are not seeing updates to published fields flow to the client that is another bug so make a simplified reproduction and log it on github.  If I use the code above and update 'friendProfile.online' on the server the changes are correctly propagated to the client.

Answer (score 1):

As given in a comment, [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/903) link reveals your problem. The current DDP Protocol does not allow publishing of subdocuments. One way to get around this is to create a separate collection with your data but a better way would probably to just remove some of the data and make it a direct object off of your user.

The best way to do this is add the data to your user's profile upon insert and then in the [`onCreateUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) move the data onto the user directly:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if (options.profile) {
        if (options.profile.publicData) {
            user.publicData = options.profile.publicData;
            delete options.profile.publicData;
        }
        user.profile = options.profile;
    }
    return user;
});
```

If you are allowing clients to perform user inserts make sure you validate the data better though. This way you can have the `online`, `favorites`, and `friends` in the profile and publish that specifically when you want it. You can then have `username` and `avatar_url` in the `publicData` object directly on the user and just always publish all-the-time.

Comment: interesting way!  But this cause a big problem... in client Meteor.user() not contains field publicData, but only profile!! I think this is caused from default fields sending by accounts-base package. I dont know how to solve this

Comment: @StefanoCudini does the server contain a publicData object on the root (so not nested in the profile) if you do this approach?

Comment: I'm edited users collection(move fields from profile to publicData), but in this way at client Meteor.user not contains publicData but only profile empty

Comment: @StefanoCudini I understand your issue, but have you checked in your mongodb on the **server** to see if the data is being saved at all?

Comment: yes I'm using mongo console(for server) and chrome console for client, may be now I resolved using custom publish of curreUser(including publicData field and profile field for logged user